# Installing Bootstrap theme make menu Disappear

Tags: yii

I have problem when I finished Installing the bootstrap theme in my Web.
Before I installing the theme,  the menu is still there.
But after I installing the theme, menus that I make is Disappeared.
menus that appeared just the default menus, like home, about, contact, login.

For Information, I Installed the bootstrap theme from this link
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/

I download the newest from the link.

Did anyone ever have experienced like me?
or Anyone Can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: what is `yii` got to do with it? and how did you great this `menu` is it some sort of other theme like bootstrap you installed?

Comment: I just want the menu that I make didn't disappeared.

It's main menu like Register.

Comment: I know that the css class names changed in the new bootstrap version. May be your problem for that.

Comment: Actually this is have been solved.
I must move the layout/main.php to the theme folder.
:D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to -->

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/classgenerator/themes/bootstrap/views/layouts/main.php

Add new item to items array of: `bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar`